# Not able to select href of a tag with Xpath (rvest)

Tags: r, rvest

I am scraping https://ic.gc.ca/eic/site/bsf-osb.nsf/eng/h_br02281.html with the `rvest` package in R. I would like to get the hyperlink associated with the company name. That portion of the html code looks like this:
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhjTN.png)

My code looks like this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url = "https://ic.gc.ca/eic/site/bsf-osb.nsf/eng/h_br02281.html"
ccaa = read_html(url)

links = ccaa %>%
  html_nodes("body") %>%
  xml_find_all("//td[1]//a[@href]") %>%
  html_text()
```

But this is only returning the names of the firms/cases, not the links that they are associated with.
How can I get these links? The end goal of this is to put these links into a data frame (along with other information) which will be rendered in a Shiny data table. Then, when a user is interested in a particular insolvency case, they can click on the link to see more information.

I am somewhat new to R and asking quesitons on stack overflow so please let me know if you require more information.

Comment: Html_text returns the content inside the node <a href=link>text</a> so text not link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `html_text` with `html_attr('href')`.